# Can I have two sockets in the same server project?

Tags: c#, sockets

I m trying a multimedia project in C# using socket programming , the program have a chat room and video streaming.
the problem is i can't differentiate between different bytes arrays for Video Streaming and for Chatting. 
I tried using two sockets,TCP Socket for Chatting and UDP for Video Streaming , but my Server won't run.

Can't I use two different sockets in the same project? and is there a way to differentiate between the types of bytes array Text or Bitmap(for Video Streaming)?.

Comment: Of course you can use 2 sockets in the same project. You will receive byte arrays over the socket. You have to know what they mean yourself by making distinction between the sockets. A TCP socket and a UDP socket are anyway entirely different in behaviour.

Comment: You can certainly have more than one socket (assuming each is using a unique port).  You'll need to be more specific than "My server won't run" in order to get more assistance.  Could you share some code?

Comment: Yea , but how can i differentiate between the types of bytes array (text or streaming) , so i can use each one with its corresponding socket? i mean by won't run that the application form wont show, it shows there's no errors but nothing go on the screen.

Comment: Please share your Program.cs file with us.  Also, you wouldn't need to differentiate between types of byte arrays if you have 2 sockets.  (One for chatting and one for video streaming.  If you DID want to use the same socket, you'd have to do something like format your text messages with a header string of text (something lik "<text>") and analyze the byte array as it comes in to see if it contains "<text"> at the beginning.  Then you'd have to strip off that header.  If it doesn't have the header at the beginning, then you can safely assume it's a streaming array.  I suggest using 2 sockets.

Comment: if your form does not show up your problem might be a lot more basic than the socket problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments , i managed to send the byte array on two different sockets and it worked , now i m having a problem converting the byte array to Bitmap to show on Picture Box , and i m managed to find a lot of topics to help me with that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AbdLoulou, I recommend that you write an answer to your own question with the solution to your problem.